# jqgrid How to use jquery blockUI plugin in inline Save command

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQGrid that utilizes both inline and form editing and uses blockUI to show a 'Please wait while your request is processed.' 
What i want is to know where to catch the event that is fired when the 'Save' icon is clicked (before the request is sent to the server) so I can use blockUI.

This is my jQGrid:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $("#<%= txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
                $("#<%= txtToDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
                //document.getElementById('Form').setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
                var filterList = "{ \"groupOp\": \"AND\", \"rules\": [{ \"field\": \"FromDate\", \"op\": \"cn\", \"data\":\"" + FromDateCtrl.val() + "\"},{ \"field\": \"ToDate\", \"op\": \"cn\", \"data\":\"" + ToDateCtrl.val() + "\"}] }";

                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid({
                        url: "/DesktopModules/UsersAdmin/Services/UsersAdminService.svc/GetAllUsers",
                        datatype: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        mtype: "POST",
                        serializeRowData: function(postdata) {
                                $(this).block(
                                {
                                        message: "<h5>Saving the data...</h5>"
                                });
                                return postdata;
                        },
                        //ajaxRowOptions: {
                        //    beforeSend: function () {
                        //        $(this).block(
                        //        {
                        //             message: "<h5>Saving the data...</h5>"
                        //        });
                        //    }
                        //},
                        height: "auto",
                        colNames: [
                                "Edit | Delete",
                                "MemberId",
                                "FirstName",
                                "LastName",
                                "Password",
                                "ConfirmPassword",
                                "CompanyName",
                                "ContactEmail",
                                "RegisteredDate",
                                "MemberApproved",
                                "MemberApprovedDate",
                                "FranchiseeDocumentStatus",
                                "FranchiseeDocumentSentDate",
                                "FranchiseeStatus"
                        ],
                        colModel: [
                                {
                                        name: "EditAction",
                                        width: 60,
                                        fixed: true,
                                        search: false,
                                        sortable: false,
                                        resize: false,
                                        formatter: "actions",
                                        formatoptions: {
                                                keys: false,
                                                editbutton: true,
                                                delbutton: true,
                                                editformbutton: false,
                                                editOptions: {

                                                },
                                                onSuccess: function(response) {
                                                        if (response.status === 200) {
                                                                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                                                                        resizable: true,
                                                                        height: 175,
                                                                        width: 325,
                                                                        modal: true,
                                                                        buttons: {
                                                                                "OK": function() {
                                                                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                                                                }
                                                                        }
                                                                });
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                                                var sel_id = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                                                                var value = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "MemberId");
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { MemberId: value });
                                                                return [false];
                                                        } else {
                                                                return [true];
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
                                                        var sel_id = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                                                        var value = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "MemberId");

                                                        if (response.responseText == "") {
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { MemberId: value });
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit

                                                                return [true, ""];
                                                        } else {
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { MemberId: value });
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                                                divloading.css("display", "none");
                                                                return [false, response.responseText];
                                                                //Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                extraparam: {
                                                        oper: "edit",
                                                        MemberId: function() {
                                                                var sel_id = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                                                                var value = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "MemberId");
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "Password", { editrules: { required: false } });
                                                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "ConfirmPassword", { editrules: { required: false } });

                                                                return value;
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                url: "/DesktopModules/UsersAdmin/Services/JQGridHandler.ashx"
                                        }
                                },
                                { name: "MemberId", index: "MemberId", width: 30, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: false },
                                { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 60, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: true },
                                { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 60, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: true },
                                { name: "Password", index: "Password", width: 60, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, edittype: "password", hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true, required: false } },
                                { name: "ConfirmPassword", index: "ConfirmPassword", width: 60, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, edittype: "password", hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true, required: false, custom: true, custom_func: checkpassmatch } },
                                { name: "CompanyName", index: "CompanyName", width: 80, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: true },
                                { name: "ContactEmail", index: "ContactEmail", width: 80, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: true },
                                { name: "RegisteredDate", index: "RegisteredDate", width: 40, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: false, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d M Y" } },
                                { name: "MemberApproved", index: "MemberApproved", width: 40, editable: true, align: "center", edittype: "checkbox", formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatoptions: { disabled: true }, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq"], value: "true:Checked;false:Unchecked" } },
                                { name: "MemberApprovedDate", index: "MemberApprovedDate", width: 40, title: false, search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] }, sortable: true, editable: false, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d M Y" } },
                                { name: "FranchiseeDocumentStatus", index: "FranchiseeDocumentStatus", width: 40, editable: true, align: "center", edittype: "checkbox", formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatoptions: { disabled: true }, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq"], value: "true:Doc sent;false:Doc not sent" } },
                                { name: "FranchiseeDocumentSentDate", index: "FranchiseeDocumentSentDate", width: 40, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: false, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d M Y" } },
                                { name: "FranchiseeStatus", index: "FranchiseeStatus", width: 40, title: false, search: true, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Their Solicitor:Their Solicitor;Our Solicitor:Our Solicitor;Franchisee:Franchisee" }, stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq"], value: "Their Solicitor:Their Solicitor;Our Solicitor:Our Solicitor;Franchisee:Franchisee" } }
                        ],
                        pager: "#UserGridPager",
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100],
                        viewrecords: true,
                        jsonReader: {
                                repeatitems: false,
                                id: "MemberId"
                        },
                        sortname: "MemberId",
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        loadui: "block",
                        autowidth: true,
                        altclass: "odd",
                        altRows: true,
                        //multiselect: true,
                        caption: "Users Management",
                        editurl: "/DesktopModules/UsersAdmin/Services/JQGridHandler.ashx",
                        toppager: true,
                        postData: {
                                filters: filterList
                        },
                        beforeRequest: addDateTimeParams,
                        onSelectRow: function(id) {
                                $("#" + id + "_" + "FirstName").attr("disabled", true);
                                $("#" + id + "_" + "LastName").attr("disabled", true);
                                $("#" + id + "_" + "CompanyName").attr("disabled", true);
                                $("#" + id + "_" + "ContactEmail").attr("disabled", true);

                                //$("#UserGrid").jqGrid("saveRow", id,
                                //{
                                //    aftersavefunc: function(response) {
                                //        $(this).block({ message: "<h4>Saving the data...</h4>" });
                                //    },
                                //    errorfunc: function(response) {
                                //        $(this).block({ message: "<h4>Saving the data...</h4>" });
                                //    },
                                //    successfunc: function(response) {
                                //        $(this).block({ message: "<h4>Saving the data...</h4>" });
                                //    }
                                //});
                        },
                        aftersavefunc: actionAfterSave,
                        errorfunc: actionOnError
                });

                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("filterToolbar", { stringResult: true });

                function actionAfterSave() {
                        alert("asdsadsad");
                        //$(this).unblockUI();
                };

                function actionOnError() {
                        alert("asdsadsad");
                        //$(this).unblockUI();
                };


                //Form pop-up edit
                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#UserGridPager",
                {
                        add: true,
                        edit: true,
                        del: true,
                        search: true,
                        searchtext: "Search",
                        addtext: "Add",
                        edittext: "Edit",
                        deltext: "Delete",
                        refresh: true,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        closeAfterEdit: true
                },
                {
                        //EDIT portion
                        //Can also set the width and height of the editing window as below commented way 
                        //height: 300,
                        //width: 400,
                        //top: 50,
                        //left: 100,
                        //dataheight: 280,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true, //Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                        drag: true,
                        beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                                // "editmodlist"
                                var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                dlgDiv[0].style.top = "50%";
                                dlgDiv[0].style.left = "50%";

                                $("#tr_FirstName", form).hide();
                                $("#tr_LastName", form).hide();
                                $("#tr_Password", form).hide();
                                $("#tr_ConfirmPassword", form).hide();
                                $("#tr_CompanyName", form).hide();
                                $("#tr_ContactEmail", form).hide();
                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "Password", { editrules: { required: false } });
                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "ConfirmPassword", { editrules: { required: false } });
                        },
                        onclickSubmit: function(params, posdata) {
                                var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                dlgDiv.css("height", 220);
                                dlgDiv.append(divloading);
                                divloading.css("display", "block");
                        },
                        afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
                                if (response.responseText == "") {
                                        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                        var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                        var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                        dlgDiv.css("width", 300);
                                        dlgDiv.css("height", 220);
                                        divloading.css("display", "none");
                                        return [true, ""];
                                } else {
                                        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                        var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                        var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                        divloading.css("display", "none");
                                        dlgDiv.css("width", 300);
                                        dlgDiv.css("height", 220);
                                        return [false, response.responseText];
                                        //Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                                }
                        },
                        editData: {
                                MemberId: function() {
                                        var sel_id = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                                        var value = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "MemberId");
                                        return value;
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        //ADD portion
                        closeAfterAdd: true, //Closes the add window after add
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                                $("#tr_FirstName", form).show();
                                $("#tr_LastName", form).show();
                                $("#tr_Password", form).show();
                                $("#tr_ConfirmPassword", form).show();
                                $("#tr_CompanyName", form).show();
                                $("#tr_ContactEmail", form).show();
                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "Password", { editrules: { required: true } });
                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "ConfirmPassword", { editrules: { required: true } });
                        },
                        onclickSubmit: function(params, posdata) {
                                var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                dlgDiv.css("height", 380);
                                dlgDiv.append(divloading);
                                divloading.css("display", "block");
                        },
                        afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
                                if (response.responseText == "") {
                                        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after Add
                                        var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                        var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                        dlgDiv.css("width", 306);
                                        dlgDiv.css("height", 320);
                                        divloading.css("display", "none");
                                        return [true, ""];
                                } else {
                                        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //Reloads the grid after Add
                                        var dlgDiv = $("#editmodUserGrid");
                                        var divloading = $("#progressDialog");
                                        divloading.css("display", "none");
                                        dlgDiv.css("width", 306);
                                        dlgDiv.css("height", 320);
                                        return [false, response.responseText];
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        //DELETE
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        closeAfterDelete: true,
                        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                        drag: true,
                        afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
                                if (response.responseText == "") {
                                        $("#UserGrid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
                                        return [false, response.responseText];
                                } else {
                                        $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                                        return [true, response.responseText];
                                }
                        },
                        delData: {
                                MemberId: function() {
                                        var sel_id = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                                        var value = $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getCell", sel_id, "MemberId");
                                        return value;
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        //SEARCH
                        multipleSearch: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true
                }).jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#UserGridPager", {
                        caption: "Choose Columns",
                        title: "Choose Columns",
                        onClickButton: function() {
                                $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("columnChooser");
                        },
                        position: "last"
                });

                //function myformat(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                //    //return cellvalue + ' ' + rowObject.Date + ' ' + rowObject.Status;
                //    //return cellvalue + ' ' + rowObject.MemberApproved + ' ' + rowObject.MemberApprovedDate;
                //    var dateString = rowObject.MemberApprovedDate.substr(6);
                //    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                //    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                //    var day = currentTime.getDate();
                //    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                //    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                //    var strelement = "";
                //    if (rowObject.MemberApproved) {
                //        strelement = '<input type=checkbox checked=checked value=true>';
                //    } else {
                //        strelement = '<input type=checkbox value=false>';
                //    }
                //    return strelement + ' ' + date;
                //}
                function addDateTimeParams() {
                        var filter = $.parseJSON($("#UserGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam").postData.filters);
                        if (filter == null) {
                                filter = eval("(" + filterList + ")"); //JSON.stringify(filterList);
                        }
                        var rules = filter.rules;
                        var foundFromDate = false;
                        var foundToDate = false;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                                if (rules[i].field == "FromDate") {
                                        rules[i].data = FromDateCtrl.val();
                                        foundFromDate = true;
                                } else if (rules[i].field == "ToDate") {
                                        rules[i].data = ToDateCtrl.val();
                                        foundToDate = true;
                                }
                        }
                        if (!foundFromDate) {
                                filter.rules.push({ "field": "FromDate", "op": "cn", "data": FromDateCtrl.val() });
                        }
                        if (!foundToDate) {
                                filter.rules.push({ "field": "ToDate", "op": "cn", "data": ToDateCtrl.val() });
                        }

                        $("#UserGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                                postData: {
                                        filters: JSON.stringify(filter)
                                }
                        });
                }
        });
```

Any helps is appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `beforeSaveRow` callback of inline editing. Because formatter: "actions" don't have it you can use `$.jgrid.inlineEdit`:

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (options, rowid) {
        // the callback can return false to break saving
        return true;
    }
});
$("#UserGrid").jqGrid({
    ...
});
```

The callback will be applied for **all** grids. If you need to use the `beforeSaveRow` only for specific grid on the page you should test the id of the grid (`this.id` or `this.p.id`) inside of `beforeSaveRow` callback.

Comment: Hi, Oleg

Can you address my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317698/jqgrid-the-warning-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main

Thank you so much