# jqgrid The warning Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main

Tags: google-chrome, jqgrid

Oleg

Relate to this post [jqgrid How to use jquery blockUI plugin in inline Save command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301859/jqgrid-how-to-use-jquery-blockui-plugin-in-inline-save-command)

I just realized that i don't need to use both serializeRowData and beforeSaveRow. I'm using jqGrid 4.7.1 and the "Saving..." message has showed when the 'Save' icon is clicked.

But it seems just only Firefox working good (I mean the "Saving..." message is showed), My Chrome is not working (the "Saving..." message is NOT showed).
The warning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." is displayed on my Chrome. I think this is the reason the "Saving..." message is NOT showed.

I think "Saving..." message is an exist feature of jqgrid and we don't need to have  a custom message or something like that. (don't need to use both serializeRowData and beforeSaveRow)

So, my question is why Chrome is fire the warning above ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `ajaxRowOptions` option of jqGrid to set `async: true` option:

```js
ajaxRowOptions: { async: true }
```

The main difference will be that `saveRow` method will don't return correct value (`true` or `false`), but the value will be seldom used. Only `inlineNav` and `formatter: "actions"` of jqGrid 4.7.x use the returned value and hide/show/enable/disable the corresponding editing buttons. If you use `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"` you will just need to add some additional code in your callback handles to hide/show/enable/disable the corresponding editing buttons.

By the way I'm developing [new free version of jqGrid](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid) and have already rewritten some parts of `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"`. The problem with changing the states of editing buttons not exist more. So I'll remove today the line `async: false` from `saveRow` in my repository so that it will works asynchronous by default.